# How do I do the equivalent of a SQL Correlated Subquery in KDB+ / Q?

Tags: kdb, correlated-subquery

I would like to do the equivalent of the following sql in q-sql:

```
update classes c set users=(select count(*) from learners u where u.classId=c.classId)
```

Note that the difficulty is that the where clause in the inner query involves a variable from the outer query.

The closest idea I could come up with was to rename the classes column (which is the first column) in the inner query and try to access them both.

```
update users:(select count i from ( `LclassId xcol learners) where LclassId=classId) from classes
```

But this results in the error `'classId` which seems to mean that `classId` from the outer query 
is not available in the inner.

Here is some example data:

```
learners:([]classId:(1;2;3;4); userId: (1; 2; 3; 4))

classes:([]classId:1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is not possible with q-sql update.

Try the following:

`classes:classes lj select users:count i by classId from learners`

Edit: (additional update syntax when aggregating)

For this example (where all classIds appear in the learners table), you can technically achieve the same result using only the learners table.

`classes:delete userId from update users:count i by classId from learners`